# Distinct not working in Doctrine/Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Here's what I have:

```
    $tag = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->getRepository('Model:Tag')
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->where('t.name LIKE :tag')
        ->setParameter('tag', '%' . $tag . '%')
        ->distinct()
        ->getQuery();

    $tags = $tag->getResult();

    return $tags;
```

Which I return as a JSON response. Which ends up looking like this:

```
["2000", "2000", "8000", "8000", "6000", "6000", "7000", "7000", "16000", "16000", "21000", "21000",…]
```

Clearly the `distinct()` isn't working. Am I using it in correctly? I must be missing something really obvious!

Any tips are most welcome. Thanks.

---

### EDIT

I now have:

```
    $tagQuery = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->getRepository('Model:Tag')
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('DISTINCT t.name')
        ->where('t.name LIKE :tag')
        ->setParameter('tag', '%' . $tag . '%')
        ->getQuery();

    $tags = $tagQuery->getResult();
```

This returns a distinct result set like this:

```
array (size=19)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string '2000' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string '8000' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string '6000' (length=4)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string '7000' (length=4)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string '16000' (length=5)
  5 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string '21000' (length=5)
  etc...
```

So I'm moving in the right direction. But how do I just return an array of results like `[2000, 8000, 6000, ...]`? Rather than the massive array of objects I currently have?

Comment: Can you post query which is sent to DB?

Comment: You probably have that many distinct entities sharing the same value on some serialized property.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I have updated my question above to show my newest code. I think you were right Yoshi, but I still haven't got the result in the format I expect. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the update. It depends, you probably want a way to serialize your objects. If you need this often you can try a [proven bundle](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer). If it's only a few times, just iterate over your array and map the values you want (to save resources, maybe use `getArrayResult()`).

Comment: IanMcL: I suspect that is the case, yes - I've changed my query slightly as you can see in my edit above.

Comment: Yoshi: there's no way in doctrine to return a simple array of results?

Comment: You can use [getArrayResult()](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#array-hydration) in combination with [`array_column`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

Comment: Thanks - array_column is a good call. If you make that an answer, I'll mark it as correct.